# how to turn my iterative for loop into recursive code without getting a stack error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int read_file(char* filename, char **buffer) {
  FILE* file1;
  file1 = fopen(filename, "r");

  //gets the size of the file
  struct stat st;
  stat(filename, &st);
  int size = st.st_size;

  *buffer = malloc(size);
  fread(*buffer, size, 1, file1);
  fclose(file1);

  return size;
}

void write_file(char* filename, char*buffer, int size) {
  FILE* file2 = fopen(filename, "w"); int k;

  for (k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    fwrite(buffer + k, 1, 1, file2);
  }

  fclose(file2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char* buffer;
  char* filename1;
  char* filename2;
  int filesize;
  
  //create an array and for loop to call the fread more than once

  filename1 = "Bible.txt";
  filename2 = "reverse.txt";

  filesize = read_file(filename1, &buffer);
  write_file(filename2, buffer, filesize);

  free(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Some info: I was able to successfully reverse a text file of a textbook, however I used iterative. It is also supposed to be written recursively but I keep getting stack errors. Any ideas are appreciated on what I can try.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your attempted recursive implementation.

Comment: The code you gave doesn't look recursive.

Comment: What parts of the currently shown code do you want to make recursive? And *why*? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think a recursive solution would be better than an iterative?

Comment: Also remember that all compilers for a typical PC-type computer uses the stack for function arguments and local variables (plus some other things). And that the stack is a limited resource. If the call-stack gets too deep then the programs just runs out of space for the stack (you get a *stack overflow*). So i you want to use recursion to read or write a large file, that might simply not be possible.

Comment: recursive is not better but it is part of my assignment, im supposed to make an iterative version and recursive version but i have been hitting a wall of stack overflow for the past week

Comment: the file it is supposed to read contains 4 million characters i have tried an array along with if statements i was sure would work

Comment: Perhaps the goal of the exercise is to make you run into that wall? To learn that while recursion is a kind of iteration, it has limitations straight-up iterative loops doesn't have?

Comment: "[T]he file it is supposed to read contains 4 million characters" Well there's definitely a problem. The default stack for Windows processes is only a single MiB (i.e. a little over one million bytes). Each recursive call will use *much* more than a single byte of stack, so all it can handle is a few tens of thousands of characters (Linux have 8 MiB, so can handle a few hundred-thousand characters). There usually are options to increase the stack-size for programs, but I don't know them and have never used them on modern systems.

Comment: Without seeing your recursive code it is difficult to suggest improvements. In case you have recursive calls for every character, maybe you can change the program to use one recursion per line of input in one function and maybe another function to recursively reverse the characters in a single line.

Comment: The question you ought to ask yourself is _why_ it must be done with recursion. A loop is always faster, safer, more readable and less memory consuming. Recursion can at best be equally fast. _Because recursion!_ isn't a rationale, it's some sort of subjective religious expression of personal believes.